# html value up down arrows

Tags: html

I know this is an extremely simple question... but I do not know the name of the element I am looking for so I can not research it.

I am looking to add one of those up/down arrow buttons that allows you to increment a textbox.

Comment: Do you mean a scroll bar? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can wait for HTML5, you could have used [`input type="number"`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html) for this. You can find [here a link to a live example](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) (works in browsers supporting HTML5 only though, currently that's only [Opera](http://www.opera.com/download/)).

But until then you'll need to look around for a Javascript library using the keyword ["spinner"](http://google.com/search?q=javascript+spinner).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're talking about is a [Number Spinner/UI Spinner](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/UI/spinner/spinner.html).

You'll need javascript in order to do something like this. Here is a [jQuery](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-ui-spinner/) example that you might find useful.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Is there not an html spinner... that's a shame. Thanks :)

Comment: Only in HTML5, also see my answer.